# как преобразовать дату в другой формат

Tags: java, строки, дата, форматирование, конвертирование-даты

Мне нужно преобразовать дату из строки формата `2 апреля 2023 г.` в другой формат `02.04.2023`

Answer (score 2):

Для парсинга даты следует воспользоваться Java Date/Time API с локализированным форматтером [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String pattern, Locale locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-), затем отформатировать полученный экземпляр `LocalDate` в другом нужном формате `dd.MM.yyyy`:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.*;
import java.util.*;

String str = "20 апреля 2023 г.";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
    "dd MMMM yyyy г.", new Locale("ru", "RU")
);
DateTimeFormatter to = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyy");

LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);

System.out.println("Дата: " + d + " -> " + d.format(to));
```

```
Дата: 2023-04-20 -> 20.04.2023
```

Если *необходимо* получить класс `java.util.Date` при помощи локализованного экземпляра [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-), это можно сделать аналогично:

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdFrom = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "dd MMMM yyyy г.", new Locale("ru", "RU")
);
SimpleDateFormat sdTo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

Date dd = sdFrom.parse(str);

System.out.println(dd + " -> " + sdTo.format(dd));
// -> Thu Apr 20 00:00:00 GMT 2023 -> 20.04.2023
```

Comment: Нужен выход в формате DD.MM.YYYY, а получается YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: Смотрите обновленный ответ